# Why don't link pseudo-classes work on class selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uvrprxko/1/) illustrating the problem.

With this CSS:

```
.btn {position:relative; width:auto; background:#2c96c9; color:#fff; cursor:pointer}
.btn a:link {color:#fff; text-decoration:none}
.btn a:visited {color:#fff; text-decoration:none}
.btn a:hover {color:#000; text-decoration:none}
.btn a:active {color:#000; text-decoration:none}
```

None of the `a:` rules are applied to this HTML:

```
<a class="btn" href="http://google.com">Why doesn't this work?</a>
```

Why?  Or what is the proper way to get them to apply to HTML links?

Comment: The selectors `:link`, `:visited`, `:hover` and `:active` are [pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) not pseudo elements. `::after` and `::before` are examples of [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)...

Comment: The space between `.btn` and `a` means to look for an anchor that's a descendant of an element with the class `.btn`.

Comment: @War10ck - thanks; just fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selectors don't work because you currently select an `a` tag inside an element of class `.btn`, because the [space in selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) means selecting a descendant. As it is written now, it would suggest a markup like this:

```
<div class="btn" >
    <a href="http://google.com">Why doesn't this work?</a>
</div>
```

But for `<a class="btn" href="...">...</a>` You should use:

```
.btn {position:relative; width:auto; background:#2c96c9; color:#fff; cursor:pointer}
a.btn:link {color:#fff; text-decoration:none}
a.btn:visited {color:#fff; text-decoration:none}
a.btn:hover {color:#000; text-decoration:none}
a.btn:active {color:#000; text-decoration:none}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse the order; the element selector should be listed before the pseudoclass.